# Rectifying the image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have problem in remaping the image, I used my own millimeter sheet which contains coplanar set of points, I applied the method of direct radial alignment still the image is warped not rectified, can someone help me to find where my error is. Xw, Yw, Zw are the real world coordinates, Xf, Yf are the corresponding pixel coordinates. Cx, Cy are the coordinates of the center of distortion.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

Xd = dx*(Xf-Cx)/Sx
Yd = dy*(Yf-Cy)  
n1=6
A=np.zeros((N, n1))  
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(n1):
      A[:, 0] = Yd*Xw
      A[:, 1] = Yd*Yw
      A[:, 2] = Yd
      A[:, 3] = -Xd*Xw
      A[:, 4] = -Xd*Yw 
      A[:, 5] = -Xd
X = solution(A) 
Sr = r1_prime**2 + r2_prime**2 + r4_prime**2 + r5_prime**2
Ty = np.sqrt(Sr-np.sqrt(Sr**2-4*(r1_prime*r5_prime-r2_prime*r4_prime)**2))/(2*(r1_prime*r5_prime-r2_prime*r4_prime)**2)        
 #compute the rotation matrix components: 
 r1 = (X[0]/X[5])*Ty
 r2 = (X[1]/X[5])*Ty
 r4 = (X[3]/X[5])*Ty
 r5 = (X[5]/X[5])*Ty
 Tx = (X[2]/X[5])*Ty 
 s = -np.sign(r1*r4+r2*r5)
 r3 = np.sqrt(1-r1**2-r2**2)
 r6 = s*np.sqrt(1-r4**2-r5**2)
 r7 = np.sqrt(1-(r1**2+r4**2))
 r8 = np.sqrt(1-(r2**2+r5**2))
 r9 = np.sqrt(-1+Sr*Ty**2) 
 n11 = 2
 A1=np.zeros((N, n11))
 for i in range(N):
    for j in range(n11):
       A1[:, 0] = r4*Xw + r5*Yw +Ty
       A1[:, 1] = -Yd     
 b1 = (r7*Xw + r8*Yw)*Yd 
 U1, S1, VT1 = np.linalg.svd(A1)
 Sigma = np.zeros((A1.shape[0], A1.shape[1]))
 Sigma[:A1.shape[1], :A1.shape[1]] = np.diag(S1)
 J1 = np.zeros((A1.shape[0], A1.shape[1]))
 J1[:A1.shape[1], :A1.shape[1]] = np.linalg.inv(np.diag(S1))
 H1 = np.zeros((A1.shape[0], A1.shape[1]))
 H1[:A1.shape[0], :A1.shape[0]] = np.linalg.multi_dot([U1, J1, VT1])
 H1 = H1.T
 x1 = np.dot(H1, b1)
 f  = x1[0]
 Tz = x1[1]
 R = np.array([[r1, r2, r3], [r4, r5, r6], [r7, r8, r9]])
 def func(guess):
    k1 = guess[0]
    k2 = guess[1]
    f = guess[2]
    tz = guess[3]
    sx = guess[4]
    r = np.sqrt((dx*(Xf-Cx)/sx)**2 + (Yd)**2)
    return np.sum((Yd*(1+k1*r**2 + k2*r**4)*(r7*Xw + r8*Yw + r9*Zw + tz)-f*(r4*Xw + r5*Yw + r6*Zw + Ty))**2) 
x0 = np.array([0, 0, f, Tz, 1])
i = minimize(func, x0, method='COBYLA', options={'disp': True})
K1 = i.x[0]
K2 = i.x[1]
F = i.x[2]
Pz = i.x[3]
Sx = i.x[4]
dx_new = dx*Sx
nx, ny = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, nx, 1), np.arange(0, ny, 1))
x = X.astype(np.float32) 
y = Y.astype(np.float32)      
rd = np.sqrt((y-Cy)**2 + (x-Cx)**2)
map_x = y*(1+K11*np.power(rd, 2)+K22*np.power(rd, 4))
map_y = x*(1+K11*np.power(rd, 2)+K22*np.power(rd, 4))
imgg = cv2.remap(img, map_x, map_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Yz9.jpg)

Comment: Most folk on StackOverflow are programmers and probably don't know what a millimeter sheet with coplanar points is! You might be more likely to get an answer if you provided some background information and an image.

Comment: I am sorry I updated the photo with the code, I understood the points of calibration as I read it in Roger Tsai paper and I applied it in a code I face problems in the corrections as I understood that the remap is the main point, but still bad photo that I got, beside each minimization method gave me different values for the intrinsic parameters! I don't know!